# SQL group by columns in a table, how to get group with count = 0?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by

I am writing a shell script to generate report of record counts.

Sample Table & Data : MED_FILE_TEST_RECORD

```
================================================================================
R_ID    SOURCE  ELEMENT FILE_STATUS FILE_CREATE_TIME    FILE_NAME

================================================================================
1001    Japan   ELE01   Successful      30/05/2014 15:11:23 xxxxxx1.txt
1002    Japan   ELE01   Corrupt         30/05/2014 15:11:23 xxxxxx2.txt
1003    Japan   ELE02   Successful      30/05/2014 17:11:23 xxxxxx3.txt
1004    Japan   ELE02   Successful      30/05/2014 17:11:23 xxxxxx4.txt
1005    Japan   ELE01   Corrupt         31/05/2014 15:11:23 xxxxxx5.txt

================================================================================
```

I use the following Oracle SQL to generate report. The results with count are generated properly.

```
SELECT SOURCE, ELEMENT, FILE_STATUS, FILE_CREATE_TIME as DAY, COALESCE(COUNT(FILE_CREATE_TIME), 0) as FILE_COUNT
FROM MED_FILE_TEST_RECORD
WHERE 
(SOURCE IN ('Japan')) AND 
(ELEMENT IN ( 'ELE01', 'ELE02' )) AND 
(FILE_STATUS IN ( 'Corrupt', 'Successful' ))  AND
(FILE_CREATE_TIME BETWEEN to_date('2014-05-30 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND to_date('2014-06-01 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
GROUP BY SOURCE, ELEMENT, FILE_STATUS, FILE_CREATE_TIME
ORDER BY DAY, SOURCE, ELEMENT, FILE_STATUS desc;
```

Results with count:

```
================================================================================ 
SOURCE  ELEMENT FILE_STATUS FILE_CREATE_TIME    FILE_COUNT

================================================================================
Japan   ELE01   Successful  30/05/2014  1
Japan   ELE01   Corrupt 30/05/2014  1
Japan   ELE02   Successful  30/05/2014  2
Japan   ELE01   Corrupt 31/05/2014  1
================================================================================
```

It it possible to generate result with count = 0 included like below? So that the report reader can be clear that there is no record at certain time at certain group? Thanks!

```
================================================================================
SOURCE  ELEMENT FILE_STATUS FILE_CREATE_TIME    FILE_COUNT

================================================================================
Japan   ELE01   Successful  30/05/2014  1
Japan   ELE01   Corrupt 30/05/2014  1
Japan   ELE02   Successful  30/05/2014  2
Japan   ELE02   Corrupt 30/05/2014  0
Japan   ELE01   Successful  31/05/2014  0
Japan   ELE01   Corrupt 31/05/2014  1
Japan   ELE02   Successful  31/05/2014  0
Japan   ELE02   Corrupt 31/05/2014  0
Japan   ELE01   Successful  01/06/2014  0
Japan   ELE01   Corrupt 01/06/2014  0
Japan   ELE02   Successful  01/06/2014  0
Japan   ELE02   Corrupt 01/06/2014  0
```

Comment: Have you tried using Having clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A left join can be used to do this.

I first use a with statement get all records I want to display, then I left join it with the original table. This will make sure that all rows will be kept in, but for those that would've had no results, r.file_create_time will be NULL, so you will know these have 0 results.

```
with T1 as
(select distinct SOURCE, ELEMENT, FILE_STATUS, FILE_CREATE_TIME as DAY
 from MED_FILE_TEST_RECORD
)
select t1.*, COUNT(r.FILE_CREATE_TIME)
from T1
left outer join MED_FILE_TEST_RECORD r
-- To do a meaningfull join
on t1.source = r.source
and t1.element = r.element
and t1.filestatus = r.filestatus
and t1.filecreatetime = r.file_create_time
--- And now your original where clause
AND
(r.SOURCE IN ('Japan')) AND 
(r.ELEMENT IN ( 'ELE01', 'ELE02' )) AND 
(r.FILE_STATUS IN ( 'Corrupt', 'Successful' ))  AND
(r.FILE_CREATE_TIME BETWEEN to_date('2014-05-30 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND to_date('2014-06-01 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
GROUP BY t.SOURCE, t.ELEMENT, t.FILE_STATUS, t.FILE_CREATE_TIME
ORDER BY t.FILE_CREATE_TIME, t.SOURCE, t.ELEMENT, t.FILE_STATUS desc;
```

There might be some typos in it, but this should work.

If the table has a single primary key, this should be used instead in the `ON` clause to join the two tables.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I can achieve my desired result by (1st) compose the overall row and column by cross join. (2nd) Left join my query which will get the real data.

Answer (score 0):

To perform selections on columns created wit agregated columns (created with `GROUP BY`), you need a [`HAVING` clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_%28SQL%29), which works pretty much like the `WHERE`clause. Try adding the following at the end of your query:

```
...
HAVING FILE_COUNT = 0
```